# Gestures in activity - android

Tags: java, android

I need to implement few gestures in activity. I used Genymotion for that, saved gestures file in res/raw folder and wrote a code which is showing all good but keeps crashing the application. Does anyone know what could be the possible reason? I really tried to solve, but it seems i am missing something!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    GestureOverlayView gesturesView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
    View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_garden,
            null);
    gesturesView.addView(inflate);
    gesturesView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    gestures = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!gestures.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(gesturesView);
    }


public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestures.recognize(gesture);
    int index = 0;
    double maxScore = predictions.get(index).score;
    for (int i = 1; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
        if (predictions.get(i).score > maxScore) {
            index = i;
            maxScore = predictions.get(i).score;
        }
    }
    Prediction p = predictions.get(index);

    if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase("Love"))
        daisy.setImageResource(sp.getInt("Love", 0));
    if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase("Hit"))
        daisy.setImageResource(sp.getInt("Hit", 0));
    if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase("Pet"))
        daisy.setImageResource(sp.getInt("Pet", 0));
    Toast.makeText(this, p.name + "\n" + p.score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Post the crash log, get it from Logcat

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your code, what happen if you don't get any prediction?

Well, `index` will be equals to `0`, and `predictions.get(index)` will crash because there is no object at index 0.

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestures.recognize(gesture);
    if (predictions == null || predictions.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    // continue the regular flow
}
```